# Renaming Variables And Method Names In A Python Source File

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a Python program that will basically take as input a raw Python source file and change all variable names to V, and all method or function names to F and leave everything else as is. So I'm trying to achieve this:

Input:

```
def gcd(x, y):
    """Sample docstring."""
    if x == y:
        return x
    if x > y:
        if y == 0: return x
        return gcd(x-y, y)
    if y > x:
        if x == 0: return y
        # Sample comment.
        return gcd(x, y-x)
```

Output:

```
def F(V, V):
    """Sample docstring."""
    if V == V:
        return V
    if V > V:
        if V == 0: return V
        return F(V-V, V)
    if V > V:
        if V == 0: return V
        # Sample comment.
        return F(V, V)
```

Everything else in the Python source file will be kept as is, including comments, docstrings, etc. I'm not entirely sure how to do this, as I would also like to later on be able to do this same sort of processing with Java and C++ files. (I.E. Change all variable names to V and all function/method names to F). Therefore, using something like the Python tokenize module or the Python ast module might not be the best option, as this will limit me to only being able to process Python source files, and not Java or C++ files.

I have already made an attempt using PLY, but the issue is, I have to specify all regular expression rules, and the whole Python grammar. There must be an easier way to achieve what I'm trying to do? Or is that the only way possible if I plan on dealing with Java and C++ source code files at a later stage?

Would be really great if I could get some idea or feedback on what the best option is to go about this.

Comment: But function names and variable names are the same thing. When you see the identifier `sum` in code, how will you know whether it's referring to the built-in function `sum`, or an integer the user is using to calculate the total of something? To _really_ find out, you'd have to run the program, and then you're running into the Halting Problem.

Comment: I suppose you can do a simple approximation, by taking the names defined as functions using `def` as functions, and everything else as variables.

Comment: Unless you're willing to implement a parser to do this, regex will get you nowhere.

Comment: @RevanProdigalKnight Read the question, he tried using PLY.

Comment: Well, there is the option of PLYPlus, which already has the Python grammar defined as an example for people who want to use it for other languages. I used that for my compilers class in college.

Comment: @Curiosity Since lex/yacc is rather popular I suppose other languages have grammars already defined for them as well.

Comment: [`ast`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html) rewrite ?

Comment: what if you go `func = lambda x: x`?

Answer (score 1):

If you have that kind of code you could use two regex. One to get the function name and other to get the variables.

If you use this regex:

```
\w+(?=\()|\b[xy]\b
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/lJ1rP1/1)**

You can see that it matches everything you need.

So, you can use both regex separatedly to replace with the content you want. The first step would be the function name replacement using:

```
\w+(?=\()
```

Second regex would be to replace X and Y by V:

```
\b[xy]\b
```

[image]

### First regex:

[image]

### Second regex:

[image]

Comment: Regexes should not and cannot be used to parse anything of this complexity, a trivial way to break your regex is by doing " x == y. ".

Comment: @simonzack I completely agree with you. I wouldn't use regex for this but since there is no answer this could provide an option to OP.